Getting a 403 error when trying to connect to storage account from Databricks Unity Catalog
I set up a Databricks instance with Unity Catalog enabled. I have set up a system-assigned managed identity Databricks Access Connector, and I have assigned the access connector to the Storage Blob Data Contributor role. Everything was working fine, and I set up the storage account as an external location on Unity Catalog and was able to read/write data to it.
Decided to create a VM jumpbox to bump up the security around access to the underlying data within the storage account (which would only be made possible for selected users accessing the storage account via the VM). I created a VNET with a subnet and a Microsoft.Storage Service Endpoint. I then changed the Networking settings on the storage account, from 'Enable from all networks' to 'Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses'. I added the VNET, the Databricks Access Connector and Azure Data Factory to the list of Resource Instances in the firewall (set to .
I am able to connect and access the data in the containers just fine from within the VM, I am able to successfully test the connection to the storage account with Azure Data Factory as well. But unfortunately, I am not able to read/write data to the storage account.
And I getting a 403 error with a link to the following message:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
        "message": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:1d66f454-a01f-0045-599f-2bea5e000000\nTime:2024-10-31T14:13:32.0426358Z"
    }
}

Things that I have tried to solve this:

Assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor role all the relevant system-assigned managed identity of the Databricks-related apps (The access connector, the actual databrickapp, Databricks Resource Provider, AzureDatabricks etc) - Same error.


Was hoping one of those managed identities is providing authentication (In my understanding this is coming from the access connector - but I had to be sure by trying all of them out)
2. Tried to whitelist all the relevant Service Tags IPs for Azure Databricks - Same error
Thought maybe whitelisting the IPs would manage to get past the firewall rules.

I am relatively new to databricks on azure - not sure what I am overlooking. Have anyone else had a issue with this before?
I am trying to avoid using a Private Endpoints as much as possible and trying to resolve this by going through whitelisting.


azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request.  Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

The blob container could be having Private ACL, which is why an authorization header is required.
To make the blobs directly accessible via URL without needing authorization (or even a SAS URL),
you could change the container’s ACL to Blob or Public.
To generate a SAS token from the portal:
Go to Storage Account > Shared Access Signature > check the required fields then click Generate SAS Token.

The available resource types you can specify are:

Service
Container
Object

Once the SAS token is genrated you can access directly the URL like below format:
f"abfss://<Container>@<Storgare Account>.dfs.core.windows.net/empcsv.csv"

Reference: Hitting a stubborn ClientAuthenticationError while attempting to use the ContainerClient class

Thanks for your reply. Looked into the issue we were having a but further and there were some NCC settings that were not available in the network setting in the Databricks workspace for the region the workspace was set up.
